# Python import statement throws exception

Tags: python

I have some code that looks like this

```
try:
  import calvin.reasoning.rule_list
except:
  print "rule_list exception"
```

And I have commented out every import statement in rule_list.py, so it looks like this

```
#import quantities
#import rules
#from conclusions import Conclusion
#from conclusions import Data
#from confidence import Validity
```

If I delete the contents of rule_list my program runs, but why would python throw an exception if there is not a circular import?

Here is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/paul/projects/branchCalvin/Calvin/src/cscience/components/c_calibration.py", line 18, in <module>
    import calvin.reasoning.rule_list
  File "/home/paul/projects/branchCalvin/Calvin/src/calvin/reasoning/rule_list.py", line 37, in <module>
    import rules
  File "/home/paul/projects/branchCalvin/Calvin/src/calvin/reasoning/rules.py", line 32, in <module>
    import engine
  File "/home/paul/projects/branchCalvin/Calvin/src/calvin/reasoning/engine.py", line 33, in <module>
    import conclusions
  File "/home/paul/projects/branchCalvin/Calvin/src/calvin/reasoning/conclusions.py", line 31, in <module>
    import samples
  File "/home/paul/projects/branchCalvin/Calvin/src/calvin/reasoning/samples.py", line 30, in <module>
    from cscience import datastore
ImportError: cannot import name datastore
problem importing module components.c_calibration
(<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>, ImportError('cannot import name datastore',), <traceback object at 0x9ebc554>)
```

Comment: Where are you importing it? Can you show some more code in `rule_list.py`? Also, try raise it from the except block, and post the full traceback.

Comment: Here is the full traceback

rule_list exception <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>
problem importing module components.c_calibration
(<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>, ImportError('cannot import name datastore',), <traceback object at 0xaceb57c>)

Comment: That doesn't look like a trace, just an exception report.

Comment: There might be not a circular import, it seems like you're importing something invalid from `rule_list`.

Comment: it looks like the cscience module may not contain datastore, or you can't access the cscience module at all (possibly because it isn't on the python path)